# Errors running the Math.Round

Tags: java

I am taking some Lynda.com classes approved by my work and looking to learn some Java. Can someone please tell me why I am getting an error with the Round and Absolute functions?

The error I am seeing is 'Cannot resolve method round(double)'.  I get the same error with the absolute value.  All I am doing is pretty much copying what the instructor is giving me.

I am just doing some simple Math calculations:

```
public class Math {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int intValue1 = 56;
        int intValue2 = 42;

        int result1 = intValue1 + intValue2;
        System.out.println("Addition: " + result1);

        int result2 = intValue1 - intValue2;
        System.out.println("Subtraction: " + result2);

        int result3 = intValue1 * intValue2;
        System.out.println("Multiplication: " + result3);

        double result4 = (double) intValue1 / intValue2;
        System.out.println("Division: " + result4);

        int result5 = intValue1 % intValue2;
        System.out.println("Remainder: " + result5);

        double doubleValue = -3.999999;
        long rounded = Math.round(doubleValue);
        System.out.println("Rounded: " + rounded);

        double absValue = Math.abs(doubleValue);
        System.out.println("Absolute: " + absValue);
    }
}
```

Also please let me know if I did not perform the code tags correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your class is called `Math`, so the compiler is looking for a method `round()` on your class, which doesn't exist.

Rename your class to `MyJavaLesson` or somesuch, and then the compiler will know you want methods from `java.lang.Math`.

You should never name your own classes with the same name as a class from anything under the `java` package, because it usually leads to confusion (as it has here).

Comment: You **never** need to import classes from `java.lang`

Answer (score 0):

See if replacing `double doubleValue` to `float doubleValue` helps you.The `Math.round()` functions takes float as its arguements.
Dont forget to add `f` after the float number assignment i.e `float doubleValue = -3.999f`.

Comment: `Math.round` has two overloads, one for `float` and one for `double` (and in each case _one_ argument).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that this class is named **Math** **(at the very top: public class Math {)**. Which overwrites the **Math** toolkit provided by java. If you name your class and file to something else it should be fine. 
p.s. generally by convention, we don't use capital letters in class and file names; to avoid these from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help on this.  Also, not sure if asking this question is allowed on this forum but was just curious how others learned Java?  I am considering take a class at a community college but wondering if I am just better off learning from Lynda.com, Udemy, and Coursera.